# Laravel Envoy on fortrabbit

Tags: laravel, ssh, fortrabbit, laravel-envoy

I've setup a Laravel app on a Fortrabbit server. I can do the following

```
$ ssh user@server
$ cd htdocs
$ php artisan migrate
```

Which works *perfectly* fine.

But I'm trying to use Envoy for tasks like this. So I've made a simple task:

```
@servers(['test' => 'user@server'])

@task('task:test', ['on' => 'test'])
    cd htdocs
    php artisan migrate
@endtask
```

However, I encounter the following issue when doing so:

```
$ envoy run task:test

[user@server]: \(><)/ Welcome to the rabbit hole. \(><)/
[user@server]: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

It might be worth noting that the db connection uses credentials from ENV variables set in the Fortrabbit interface. If i SSH into the server and do `env`, all the variables are listed as they should be. But when doing

```
$ ssh user@server env
```

I only get a small portion of the Fortrabbit server ENV variables.

I can't figure out what could be the cause of the error, and I haven't been able to find anything when asking Google. Could anybody shed a bit of light on this? Thanks alot.

Comment: Presumably this is because if you use `ssh user@host command` you are executing that command rather than a login shell. As such, you may not get certain environment variables set (for example, those set in a bashrc file). As for how to fix this I don't know as I don't use Envoy, but if there's a way to get Envoy to create a login shell and then pipe commands to that rather than executing commands directly that'll probably do what you want.

Comment: How are you currently detecting environments ?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the error you describe but for me `php artisan env` does work as expected. Can you post the code that does environment detection ? And are you sure you're not setting the environment dynamically somewhere in the code ? That could explain why the second command by forcing --env=test_server doesn't work.

Comment: @edi9999 In bootstrap/start.php i do a closure in detectEnvironment() with the following: `return getenv('APP_ENV') ?: 'development';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ukautz said, the session scripts are not executed by envoy, that's why some of your environment variables are *missing*.

Here's what I did:

```
@servers(['dev'=>"<<user@server>>"])
@task('list')
    . /etc/profile.envvars
    env
@endtask
```

That showed all ENV variables, including those set by you on the dashboard !

Your script should work with this:

```
@servers(['test' => 'user@server'])
@task('task:test', ['on' => 'test'])
    . /etc/profile.envvars
    cd htdocs
    php artisan migrate
@endtask
```

Comment: That did the trick. Although I need to use the '. /etc/profile.envvars' on all tasks, but that'll do. :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to check if your environment dedection works as expected.

```
$ php artisan env
```

If not, your can force the environment for artisan commands, like so:

```
$ php artisan migrate --env=test_server
```

Comment: Doing `php artisan env` in my Envoy tasks returns `development` which obviously isn't correct. However, I did try to force the stage environment as suggested: `php artisan migrate --env=stage`, which threw the exact same PDOException as earlier. If I, through Envoy, do `cd htdocs` and `env` I only get a small portion of the ENV variables as stated earlier. If I SSH in to the server normally, not through Envoy, and do `env` they are all listed. Furthermore `php artisan env` on the server through SSH results in `stage`.

Comment: The difference between (1) logging in to SSH and executing `env` and (2) executing `ssh user@server env` is:
When doing (1), you open an new shell session and session scripts like `.bash_profile` are executed.
When doing (2) you just execute a remote command and no session scripts are executed

As fortrabbit exports the environment variables in the session, you can do this:
`ssh user@server '. /etc/profile.envvars && env'`
to export the session variables you setup in the dashboard. Mind the `&&`.